# Android Paypal sdk fulfillment information

Tags: android, paypal, payment, paypal-sandbox

I'm writing an android app where customers can purchase tickets for the race track. I've got the whole paypal sandbox set up and it works to take payments. Only problem is, how would I get it to take the customers name so that I know who gets the tickets?  How do I pull the info to determine exactly who gets the tickets ie shipping info etc... Where in the api are the screens for shipping etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Jeff from PayPal at your service. The [PayPal Android SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/) does not yet support shipping addresses.  Your best bet is to use [MPL](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MPL/) until the new SDK will support this feature.